# Error: Could not initialize class com.android.sdklib.repository.AndroidSdkHandler

Tags: android, react-native

I've setup the environment for react native on Windows. But when I run the command

```
react-native run-android
```

I get the following errors -

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
   > Could not initialize class com.android.sdklib.repository.AndroidSdkHandler
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Did you follow all the instalation steps provided here: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html and selected Building project with Native Code tab

Comment: Yeah, almost. But I didn't install a few components in Android Studio. I'm installing them now. Will see if that works. Thanks.

Comment: @PaulSantosh do you have an update for this?

Comment: @Wayferer I've read somewhere that installing Java 8 would help. I installed Java 8 now it's showing this error - com.android.build.gradle.tasks.factory.AndroidJavaCompile.setDependencyCacheDir(Ljava/io/File;)V

Comment: which JDK are you using? The one embedded in Android Studio or standalone JDK?

Comment: I'm having a similar issue. @karthikk should we be using the JDK provided by Android Studio?

Comment: For me it was solved by switching back from JDK 1.9 to latest 1.8.

Comment: @martin Yes it solved for me using JDK provided by Android Studio. and AS is using JDK 1.9 FYI.

Comment: @PaulSantosh - i am having the same issue, did you solve it?

Comment: @GalBlank Yes, I've switched to JDK 1.8.0 and now it works.

Answer (score 151):

This is because your classpath build tools in build.gradle root project is deprecated. Update it like this

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.0'
    }
}
```

and after that update your minimum sdk and build tools to latest and no problem again

Comment: this work for me; I'm on windows 10 android studio 4.2 C15

Comment: With that advice, I get

Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2.
Searched in the following locations:
  - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.1.2/gradle-3.1.2.pom
  - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.1.2/gradle-3.1.2.jar
Required by:
    project :
Add google Maven repository and sync project
Open File

Comment: I'm building an old project, and this fix it for me, and build successfully.

Comment: For me the important part was adding the `google()` repository. I'm trying to build an old project from GitHub, and it only had `mavenCentral()` but that hasn't included  the build tools since 3.0

Answer (score 64):

I encountered this error while running the following command in macOS

```
./gradlew assembleRelease --stacktrace
```

and got the exact error posted.
I solved the problem by setting $JAVA_HOME environment variable to your JDK installation. In my case I used the bundled JDK in Android Studio for macOS:

```
export JAVA_HOME="/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home"
```

for Windows, just add JAVA_HOME to your user or system variables pointing to

```
"C://Program Files/Java/jdk_1.x_"
```

folder and try running react-native run-android again.

Comment: Clever fix, no need to install additional jdk!

Comment: mac fix didnt work for me.  any advice ? using java 10

Comment: Worked for me. To find java location on Windows use this in command line:   c:\> for %i in (java.exe) do @echo.   %~$PATH:i

Comment: didn't work for me; I'm on windows 10 android studio 4.2 C15

Comment: @MiguelSilva It did not work for me either. Windows 10, Android Studio 4.2.1

Answer (score 33):

This will resolve issue to follow below steps:

**1) Change Project level Gradle version ***build.gradle*****

Earlier version name like

`classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.2'`

Change with new version or latest version you have

`classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.1'`

**2) Change *gradle-wrapper.properties* from \gradle\wrapper**

Earlier version name like

`distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.8.1-bin.zip`

Change with new version or latest version you have

`distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.7.1-bin.zip`

Comment: Changing the gradle version in build.gradle only works for me. Should be an issue with gradle2

Comment: This really solved my problem.

Answer (score 16):

This is a problem with JDK version 9. Android tools does not support building with Java 9 officially yet. And it has such problems.

Downgrading to Java version 8 will fix the problem.

Comment: I'm already using Java 8 and still receiving issue :(

Answer (score 7):

On Ubuntu 18.04, this fixed the problem.

1. Run this command

   `sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk`
2. Add this to `~/.bashrc`

   `export JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64"`
3. Restart your terminal or IDE.

Answer (score 4):

According to the log, add the **google()** repository to the **build.gradle** file in the app directory as shown below:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The possible reason is the Gradle 's version and JDK's version is not matched.

At begin, My computer's gradle version is 4.10.1 and JDK is 12.

My solution is:

Download JDK 1.8 from oracle's website, set JAVA_HOME with JDK8 and It done

Comment: Maybe that is also gradle's bug or JDK12 's bug.  Haha!!

Answer (score 0):

Replace jcenter() with
google()

and

mavenCentral()

in project level gradle file

Answer (score 0):

Following below steps solved my problem,

1. Open project level build.gradle file
2. Under

   dependencies {
   classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.4'
   }
3. Updated it to

   dependencies {
   classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.1'
   }
4. sync and build the project.

I changed to version from **2.2.4** to **3.6.1**

Answer (score -1):

Fixed the error by adding the following in .bash_profile

```
 export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_171.jdk/Contents/Home
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/saif-ams/MyFiles/applications/androidsdk
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```