# Android studio gradle config error

Tags: android-studio

A problem occurred configuring project ':app':

> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
>   Could not initialize class com.android.sdklib.repository.AndroidSdkHandler

I am trying to build a project for class and have been getting this error while running the test.

What went wrong?

Comment: Possibly this covers/solves your issue : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46917365/error-could-not-initialize-class-com-android-sdklib-repository-androidsdkhandle

If not, I would advice adding more details to question, it's too broad right now and anything would be a speculation

Answer (score 1):

Change java version to 1.8, if you are using this inside app

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1- Replace in build.gradle (project)

```
 dependencies {

        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.2'

        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
    }
```

2- Replace in gradle-wrapper.properties (Gradle Version)

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.7.1-bin.zip
```